# jQuery post to c# without form

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-post

I am trying to make a jQuery POST to a c# file where the value will be saved to a DB, but the $.post is empty.

jQuery:

```
$.post("saveAccessToken.aspx", { token: 'hello'   }).done(function (data) { alert(data) });
```

c#:

```
strAccessToken = Request.Form["token"]
```

I have also tried with Request.Params and just Request. If I change it to $.GET instead it works, but I would prefer to be able to do a post.

Any ideas?

Comment: Working just fine for me so you'll have to debug. What you mean "$.post is empty"? What exactly is empty? Did you put a breakpoint in the code reading `Request.Form["token"]`?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the value is null. If I change it to $.get and request.querystring it gets the value, but otherwise it is null.

Comment: So something in your code is causing this. Try creating a blank new page both for the client side code and server side and see if it works. If it does, you have some weird conflict in your code.

Comment: Hi, tried creating a blank page only including jQuery and then running the line of code. Same result. $.get works, but on $.post Request.Form["token"] is null.

Comment: That's weird... what if you submit ordinary form, with `method="POST"` and a text box named `token`? (this would tell us if the problem is with jQuery, or the Request)

Comment: Tried that as well now. GET works, but POST still doesn't.

Comment: So something in your server is blocking POST requests. What server are you using? Try browsing with the built in Visual Studio browser and your code would likely start working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can help?

[Call ASP.Net Page Method using jQuery AJAX Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Did you use the WebMethod attribute?

Comment: Thanks! No I didn't. Just a plain .aspx file with a codebehind that handles the c#. I am not familiar with WebMethod, is it necessary to save a form like that? I have done the same thing before only I have had a form that I posted.

Comment: I dont know for sure, but in all examples i found i saw that attribute being used so i think it is necessary.

Comment: First, to accept Post requests you don't have to use Web Method. Second, this is a link only answer.

Comment: You can make this a fair answer by adding relevant parts from the links into your post, not just throwing links around asking OP to take a look.